# how to show a new todo-item without refreshing the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried a lots of things , and this problem does not seem to go away , can someone help me with this ??

this is my app component :

```
function App() {

  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);
  async function getTodo() {
    try {
      const todo = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/todos");

      // console.log(todo.data)
      setTodo(todo.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("something is wrong");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    getTodo();
  }, []);




  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>My Todo List</h1>
      <h2>My Todo List</h2>

      <Task Todor={todo} />
      <Write />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is my todos component  :

```
function Todos({ Todor }) {
    return (
        <div className="Todos">
            {Todor.map(T => <Todo post={T} />)}


        </div>
    );
}

export default Todos;
```

and this is my todo component  :

```
function Todo({ post }) {
    return (
        <div className="Todo">
            <h2>{post.title}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Todo ;
```

and this my add component :

```
export default function Write() {
    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState({
        title: ""
    });

    function handleChange(e) {
        setInputText({
            ...inputText,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    }
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
    async function addItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/todos", inputText);
        setInputText(inputText)
        console.log("response:", res)


        setStatus(true);
        setInputText("");
    }


    return (


        <div className="container">


            <div className="form">
                <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="title" />
                <button onClick={addItem}>
                    <span>Add</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}
```

the new items dont show until I refresh the page , how to do that without refreshing ?
because obviously that defeats the purpose of React !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    getTodo();
  }, []);
```

The code inside `useEffect` with empty dependencies array `[]` only runs on the first render, to run it on every render you should remove the empty array dependencies.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    getTodo();
  });
```

**Note**: It is not a best practice because your component will invoke `getTodo()` every time rerendered. In your case, you can use a state variable to control where to re-run the `getTodo` funtion e.g:

```
const [isAddedSuccess, setIsAddedSuccess] = useState(false)
```

Everytime you add new item successfully, just `setIsAddedSuccess(true)` and your `useEffect` should look like below:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    if (isAddedSuccess) getTodo();
  }, [isAddedSuccess]);
```

Comment: I tried this , and it did not work :: 

  async function getTodo() {
    try {
      const todo = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/todos");

      // console.log(todo.data)
      setIsAddedSuccess(true)
      setTodo(todo.data);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("something is wrong");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    getTodo();
  }, [isAddedSuccess]);

Comment: Just try the `useEffect` without dependencies array first to understand how the `useEffect` works. My alternative implemetation is like a recommendation, not the exact solution that works immediately after pasting to your code. it lets you have more control over your component rendering.

Comment: I did that , and it worked 
but I know that it is not best practice

Comment: To use the `isAddedSuccess` like I said. You shoud `setIsAddedSuccess(true)` everytime an item has been added succesfully and you have to reset the `isAddedSuccess` to false inside `getTodo` function, below `setTodo(todo.data)`. The idea is you should reset this state to make it false before the next adding todo.